# How to add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to an shape drawn on CAShapLayer - swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have an imageView that I have drawn a blue circle in its layer.  I would like a user to be able to tap, hold and drag this blue circle anywhere within the UIImageView.  I am unsure how to attach this shape to a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. My effort so far is below:

```
class DrawCircleViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // DRAW A FILLED IN BLUE CIRCLE
        drawBlueCircle()

        // ADD GESTURE RECOGNIZER
        let panRecgonizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: ???, action: <#T##Selector?#>)

    }

    func drawBlueCircle(){
        let fourDotLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        fourDotLayer.path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: CGRect.init(x: 60, y: 60, width: 30, height: 30), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
        fourDotLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        self.imgView.layer.addSublayer(fourDotLayer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might have noticed you can't add GestureRecognizers to CALayers. They can only be added to UIView types.

The solution is to add a subview to your imageview and draw the blue circle in it.

```
    var drawingView: UIView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        drawingView.frame = imgView.bounds
        imgView.addSubview(drawingView)
        // DRAW A FILLED IN BLUE CIRCLE
        drawBlueCircle()
        // ADD GESTURE RECOGNIZER
        let panRecgonizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: drawingView, action: #selector())
drawingView.addGestureRecognizer(panRecgonizer)
    }
    func drawBlueCircle(){
        let fourDotLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        fourDotLayer.path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: CGRect.init(x: 60, y: 60, width: 30, height: 30), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
        fourDotLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        drawingView?.layer.addSublayer(fourDotLayer)
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to use 'UIView.addGestureRecognizer' in the above?

Comment: yes I've updated the code to show it. You'll also need a method to handle the pan start

Comment: will this code actually target the specific blue circle in the subview or the entire subview given that its frame is the same as the bounds of the parent UIImageView?

Comment: this will target the entire drawingView. You should set the frame to the size of the label to have the moving effect

Answer (score 1):

use this code to move the view

```
@objc func handlePanRecgonizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
     if panRecgonizer.state == .began || panRecgonizer.state == .changed {
        let translation = panRecgonizer.translation(in: self.view)
        panRecgonizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: panRecgonizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: panRecgonizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        panRecgonizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
}
```

if you want to add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` programmatically:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanRecgonizer))
 self.someDraggableView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```